# Code complexity metrics and ifdefs

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I was wondering how standard code complexity metrics (e.g., LOC, McCabe cyclomatic complexity, Halstead metrics, etc) are computed in the face of ifdefs in C/C++ code.

If ifdefs are ignored, syntax errors (or even type errors) may arise, such as in:

1. #ifdef FOO
2. for(i = 0; i < x; i++) {
3. #else
4. for(i = 0; i < y; i++) {
5. #endif
6. printf(...)
7. }

If lines 1, 3 and 5 are ignored, the resulting code would have one loop inside the other, and a missing '}' (thus the syntax error).

If #ifdefs are taken into account, then one would need a single resulting measure per variant (in this case, one when FOO is defined, and another one for the case when FOO is not defined). However, such an approach can easily explode in practice.

Looking at http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/pmccabe.1.html, the manpage 
reports that:

*Parsing
       pmccabe ignores all  cpp  preprocessor  directives  -  calculating  the
       complexity  of  the  appearance  of the code rather than the complexity
       after the preprocessor mangles the code.  This is especially  important
       since  simple  things like getchar(3) expand into macros which increase
       complexity.*

But, as I said, this approach may lead to code errors to appear, which in turn, may hinder the calculation process or result in an incorrect value.

How do tools overcome this problem (if they overcome at all)?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

If you rewrite that construct as

```
#ifdef FOO
# define LOOPEND x
#else
# define LOOPEND y
#endif
```

or something like that, there should be no problem.

If you don't want to do that, and your complexity checker doesn't understand the preprocessor, you can run it on the output of the preprocessor, both with `FOO` defined and with `FOO` undefined, then take the max of the values it produces to get a lower bound on the actual complexity. With GCC, the preprocessor is invoked with `gcc -E`; other compilers will have a similar option.

(Of course, if you have a lot of this CPP wizardry, you're left with an exponential number of possibilities. But that's the price you pay for using the preprocessor; the same applies to testing.)

Comment: For the first part: how to measure complexity metrics in existing C/C++ code? We are talking about millions of lines of code, so rewriting is not a possibility.

Second part: it explodes given a code base with hundred of macro variables (2^n, where n denotes such macros)

Comment: @LeonardoPassos: depends. For what purpose do you need complexity figures?

Answer (score 1):

Many of the metric calculators do not use full or conforming parsers, instead they do (maybe) the first couple of phases of translation and then look for keywords.

Since they are not looking at the full syntax issues like you describe do not block them. Howevery they do become fragile in other ways, in fact I have seen cyclo-2.0 fail compleatly on solid production code.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that in a larger project (rather than a 20 line "experiment") the amount of `#ifdef` and similar that affect the ACTUAL complexity of the code would be rather minimal - you'd hope that most of those sort of expressions are in isolated units that aren't affecting the overall score too much.

But yes, if you have a small set of code with large amounts of `#ifdef` and complexity within the `#ifdef` parts, you could get a large error. Manual inspection of the code would be able to tell you this.

Comment: Hi, as stated in the above comment (see comment for larsmans), manual work or even combinatorial one is not an option :(

Comment: Yes, but my mention of manual work is only applicable for SMALL applications - if it's a large project, surely your results would be pretty much the same either way!